# Mocking a method with throw() specifier

Tags: c++, mocking, googlemock

I am trying to Google mock a virtual method which has a throw() specifier.  The original function looks like this:

```
virtual ReturnValue FunctionName() const throw();
```

I am getting the compiler error: `looser throw specifier for 'virtual FunctionSignature'`

Here is the code I have tried thus far:

```
MOCK_CONST_METHOD0( FunctionName, ReturnValue() );  
MOCK_CONST_METHOD0( FunctionName, ReturnValue() throw() );  
MOCK_CONST_METHOD0( FunctionName, ReturnValue() ) throw(); // Gives a different error entirely.
```

I've tried just about every other combination I can think of, but these are the ones which seem most logical.  How do I go about Google mocking a method with a throw() specifier?

Comment: It seems to me that Google coding style forbids exceptions entirely.

Comment: @Alexandre C: So I guess one question is, is GoogleMock designed to support code not written in Google's house style?

Comment: @Steve: my guess is no(t yet), but I don't like guessing.

Comment: They are just slow (probably because they don't care due to their guidelines). Star this bug if you want it: https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/issues/detail?id=122

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell, you'd have to use the "internal" `GMOCK_METHOD0_` macro, and use:

```
GMOCK_METHOD0_(, const throw(), , FunctionName, ReturnValue)
```

as `MOCK_CONST_METHOD0(m, F)` is #defineed to `GMOCK_METHOD0_(, const, , m, F)`, [gmock/gmock-generated-function-mockers.h#644](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/source/browse/trunk/include/gmock/gmock-generated-function-mockers.h#644) and [gmock/gmock-generated-function-mockers.h#347](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/source/browse/trunk/include/gmock/gmock-generated-function-mockers.h#347) defines that.

Comment: Cool, but obviously, the drawback of this is it might not work in the future (because it is internal).

Answer (score 1):

My solution: create an implementation of the virtual function which consists solely of passing through to a mocked method.

```
MOCK_CONST_METHOD0( MockFunctionName, ReturnValue() );
virtual ReturnValue FunctionName() const throw()  
{  
    return MockFunctionName();  
}
```

Then, whenever you need to write an Expect_Call or do anything for that method, just refer to MockFunctionName.

Comment: Ok, now how about EXPECT_THROW

Answer (score 1):

Google mock does not support exception specifications. The reason is that they think exception specification is mostly a misfeature and should be avoided in practice, even if you
use exceptions extensively.

There are some sources that supports this point of view:

- Herb Sutter (author of "Exceptional C++" and "More Exceptional
  C++"): A Pragmatic Look at Exception Specifications
  http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill22.htm
- Anders Hejlsberg (chief designer of C#): The Trouble with Checked
  Exceptions http://www.artima.com/intv/handcuffs.html

The solution would be rewriting the code as:

```
virtual ReturnValue FunctionName() const throw();
```

and then use:

```
MOCK_CONST_METHOD0( FunctionName, ReturnValue() );
```